Elliptic curves of the form $y^2=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$
It is clear that the elliptic curve $y^2=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ , $(a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q})$ has three points of order two.
What else can we say about its Mordell-Weil group?
For example, can we fix the form of its torsion subgroup? (From Magma, lots of them have $\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2$)
Can anyone recommend research papers on this specific elliptic curve form?

This is called the Legendre family.
